Как реализовать анимацию загрузки в aiogram?
Нужно реализовать анимацию загрузки до того момента пока функция get_users_from_channel() не вернула что либо, приведённый код не работает корректно, цикл длится бесконечно
        if message.text.startswith('t.me') or message.text.startswith('https://t.me'):

            file_name: None = None

            processed = await message.answer('Processing.')

            while not file_name:

                await processed.edit_text('Processing..')

                await asyncio.sleep(1)

                await processed.edit_text('Processing...')

                await asyncio.sleep(1)

                await processed.edit_text('Processing.')

                await asyncio.sleep(1)

            file_name: str = await get_users_from_channel(message.text)

